# How click to part of string of TextView in InputTextLayout (error or help message)

Tags: java, android

It's a solved problem, but I want to share my solution with community.

I use a component TextInputLayout with EditText inside.

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/emailEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"/>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

When I need to show error I use this method:

```
textInputLayout.setErrorEnabled(true);
textInputLayout.setError(errorMessage);
```

But in my case I need to show a button in a message inside errorMessage with another color and clickable.

For example my message:

```
User with this email already exist. Sign in
```

I need a clickable, bold text style **Sign in** in this message.
I used SpannableStringBuilder, changed color and created listener, but click event didn't work. And I couldn'd use method

```
TextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

for TextInputLayout or TextInputEditText.

After many hours to be trying to solve this case I found a some way, which works for me. I got a TextView from TextInputLayout by this:

```
((TextView)((FrameLayout)((LinearLayout) til.getChildAt(1)).getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(0))
                .setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

All code for creating part of message clickable in InputTextLayout:

```
textInputLayout.setErrorEnabled(true);

String text = getString("User with this email already exist. Sign in");
SpannableStringBuilder ssBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(text);

int startPoint = text.indexOf("Sign in");
int endPoint = text.indexOf("Sign in") + String.valueOf("Sign in").length();
int flags = Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE;

ssBuilder.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(@NonNull View widget) {

    //put your code here...

    widget.invalidate(); //for hide background shadow after click
  }

  @Override
  public void updateDrawState(@NonNull TextPaint ds) {
    super.updateDrawState(ds);
    ds.setUnderlineText(false);
    ds.setFakeBoldText(true);
    ds.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorWhite));
  }
}, startPoint, endPoint, flags);

((TextView)((FrameLayout)((LinearLayout) textInputLayout.getChildAt(1)).getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(0))
    .setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

textInputLayout.setError(ssBuilder);
```

Thank you for your attention!

Comment: Are you actually asking a question here? Are you asking for reviews of your solution? You might want to try https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Nope. I just wanted to share it. Because when I was looking for solution I can't find something useful.

Comment: So basically you want colored button with error and with click on that button should resolve that error!!

Comment: @kblt.27 If it isn't a question, please don't post it as one. If you have a solution you want to share you could create a question asking for a solution and then post your own answer. Other people can then contribute their own answers.

Answer (score 0):

> - I think you should try creating a `Material button` button below
>     `TextInputLayout` with visibility set to hide as this will be an
>     easier solution instead of above solution that you have provided.
> - Whenever you want to show error as well as you can handle click on that button.